# DAX code to return correct work order status

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data containing work order numbers, this data is duplicated in many instances. I am only interested in seeing the more recent in a summary table in Power BI.

Sample data:

```
Work Order No   Start Time          Finish Time         Status
4507101         11/05/2023 08:28:00 11/05/2023 13:51:00 As Per Lead Engineer Jobsheet
4507101         11/05/2023 10:44:00 11/05/2023 13:37:00 Complete
4507101         11/05/2023 08:00:00 11/05/2023 10:44:00 Incomplete
4507101         10/05/2023 08:26:00 10/05/2023 14:49:00 As Per Lead Engineer Jobsheet
4507101         10/05/2023 09:56:00 10/05/2023 14:44:00 Incomplete
4507101         10/05/2023 09:52:00 10/05/2023 12:02:00 As Per Lead Engineer Jobsheet
```

I'm interested in creating a summary table containing the most recent entry, based on the column "Finish Time". I have two statuses that I'm interested in 'Complete' and 'Incomplete'. There is however a third, 'As Per Lead Engineer'. In the instance where 'As Per ..." is the most recent entry, I need the code to bypass this and return the most recent correct status eg complete or incomplete.

The final outcome should be:

| Work Order No | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 4507101 | Complete |
| 4508101 | Incomplete |

I've tried this DAX code:

```
Table2 =
SUMMARIZE (
    'Table1 Data',
    'Table1'[Work Order No],
    "Status",
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Table1'[Status] ),
            FILTER (
                'Table1',
                'Table1'[Finish Time] = MAX ( 'Table1'[Finish Time] )
            )
        )
)
```

It is correct that it returns the most recent entry, but it does not exclude the status "As Per Lead Engineer". I thought about MAX - 1, but there might be instances where "As Per ... " is back to back etc.

Comment: The data for 4508101 seems to be missing. Is that a typo? 
If you're only interested in the "complete" or "incomplete" records, you can just filter your data down to just those:

FILTER( 'Table1 Data', [Status] IN ("Complete","Incomplete') )

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
CalculatedTable = 
VAR RelevantStatuses = FILTER(
    MyTable, 
    MyTable[Status] IN {"Complete", "Incomplete"}
)
RETURN
SUMMARIZE(
    RelevantStatuses,
    MyTable[Work Order No],
    MyTable[Status]
   -- "MaxFinish", MAX(MyTable[Finish Time])
)
```

[image]